# Different Behavior of a code using fork when run on terminal & when o/p redirected to a file

Tags: c, linux, fork

I came across some test code which is giving different output when executed on terminal directly and when its output is redirected to a file:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
     printf("hello\n");
     if(fork() ==0)
     {
            printf("world\n");
     }
}
```

On the terminal the output is:

```
abhi@ubuntu:~/Desktop/ad/A1/CC$ ./vb
hello
abhi@ubuntu:~/Desktop/ad/A1/CC$ world
```

(The cursor is still blinking after printing world & normal prompt is shown after enter is pressed.)

On redirecting output to a file:

```
./vb >v.txt
 abhi@ubuntu:~/Desktop/ad/A1/CC$ cat v.txt 
 hello
 hello
 world
```

As far as I understand the parent is not waiting for child it prints `hello` & returns. The child then should print `world` and the code should terminate.

What I am not able to understand is why the code is behaving differently when its output is redirected. What is the cause of this?

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for formatting the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When stdout is redirected to a file, it's not line buffered. When it's a tty, it is. So when writing to a tty the `printf` immediately writes to stdout and "that's all she wrote".

But when `stdout` is redirected to a file `"hello\n"` remains in the `stdio` buffer. When you `fork`, both processes (both the child and the parent) end up with a copy of the `stdio` buffers, which they flush at exit.

---

Off-topic: in my opinion `o/p` is a really really bad way to write "output" - I hate it with the white-hot intensity of a thousand suns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice explanation. sorry for the o/p

Comment: so if i will use a wait(&status) just before the main terminates then in that case child will flush out its buffer & then parent will follow.

Comment: stdio buffering details here: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/